# List manipulations with ; and ;;

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
L = {{a1,a2,a3,a4},{b1,b2,b3,b4},{c1,c2,c3,c4}}
```

By using just the `;` or `;;` "iterators", or equivalent,  how can I extract a list from `L` such that:

```
NewL = {{a1,a3},{b1,b3},{c1,c3}}
```

Up today I haven't understand exactly how to work with these list manipulation techniques. I know that `m;;n` means "partis m trough n", but at which level? And what does `;` alone stands for? Or the comma `,`?

Comment: `L[[All, {1,3}]]`. Take a look at `Part` and `Span` documentation. Moreover, single `;` is [something different](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/5478).

Comment: or L[[;; , 1 ;; ;; 2]]

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: It looks like the question will be closed soon.  After reading the documentation on `Part` and `Span`, do you still have questions?